# What's the name of this poem in Danya Ruttenberg's "Surprised by God"?

Tags: shabbat, hebrew, song-poetry

The introduction to Rabbi Ruttenberg's book features an English translation of a Hebrew poem she is singing at the beginning of a Shabbat service. The translation seems to be unique to the book, and so I couldn't find its actual Hebrew name. Here's the full quote:

> As the melody runs its course and begins to ebb, I move into the first piece of the liturgy, a medieval love poem full of longing for union with the Divine.
> *Beloved of my soul, compassionate parent, draw Your servant to Your will. Let Your servant run like a gazelle to bow down before Your splendor. Let Your affection be sweeter than a honeycomb or any other taste. Splendorous one, most beautiful radiance of the world, my soul is sick with love for You.*

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Mi Yodeya!
In Hebrew it's called "[Yedid Nefesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yedid_Nefesh)" (ידיד נפש) and commonly sung before the start of the [Kabbalat Shabbat](https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/kabbalat-shabbat/) service when Shabbat starts. The quoted part is the first stanza of the liturgical piece. As you will be able to see in the Wiki link, its authorship is disputed.

Here's a cover of one of the most well-known melodies of Yedid Nefesh:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PG7lQlofMbg